# ROCR / Gplot issue

Tags: r, installation, package, gplots

I'm trying to install the ROCR package via the following code

`install.packages("ROCR")
install.packages("gplots")
library(gplots)
library(ROCR)`

However, I am receiving the following error:

```
> library(gplots)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘gplots’ in inDL(x, 
as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...):
unable to load shared object 'REDACTED/3.4/gtools/libs/x64/gtools.dll':
LoadLibrary failure:  %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

In addition: Warning message:
package ‘gplots’ was built under R version 3.4.2 

> library(ROCR)
Loading required package: gplots
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘gplots’ in inDL(x, 
as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...):
unable to load shared object 'REDACTED/3.4/gtools/libs/x64/gtools.dll':
LoadLibrary failure:  %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

Error: package ‘gplots’ could not be loaded
In addition: Warning messages:
1: package ‘ROCR’ was built under R version 3.4.2 
2: package ‘gplots’ was built under R version 3.4.2
```

Comment: Please, could you share the output of `sessionInfo()` ?

Answer (score 0):

@Marco

Session info as follows:

R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1] Matrix_1.2-10

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.1  tools_3.4.1     yaml_2.1.14     grid_3.4.1      knitr_1.17
[6] lattice_0.20-35